# Comparing char-array in a struct with user input char-array

Tags: c, input, struct, compare, c-strings

I am writing a code to search for a specific student in a file, and calculate it's average. everything works except for one thing. When I input the student's name in a char variable, to search for him in the file, the compiler does not get it is equal to a char in the struct of the file...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define nl printf("\n")
#define N 100

struct student {
    char id[N][N];
    int vote[10][10];
};

int main()
{
struct student stud;
FILE *filer;
int i=0, j=0, k=0, n_stud=0;
char checker[1], who[N];
float avg[10], mark=0.0, count=0.0;

printf("Introduce student id: ");
scanf("%14s", &who);
printf("Searching for student %s...\n", who);
nl;

filer=fopen("students.dat", "r");
if(filer==NULL) {
    printf("Can't open file...\n");
}

for(i=0; fscanf(filer, "%s", &stud.id[i])!=NULL && fscanf(filer, "%c", &checker)!=EOF; ++i) {
    for(j=0; fscanf(filer, " %d", &stud.vote[i][j])!=-1; ++j ) {
        if(stud.vote[i][j]!=-1) {
        mark=mark+stud.vote[i][j];
        count++;
        } else {
            for(k=j; k<10; k++) {
                stud.vote[i][k]=0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    n_stud++;
    avg[i]=mark/count;
    mark=0.0; count=0.0;
}

for(i=0; i<n_stud; ++i){
    if (who == stud.id[i]) {  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!
        printf("Student %s's average is: %.2f", stud.id, avg[i]);
    }
}
nl;

fclose(filer);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

}

File

```
s11111  30  28  18  -1
sa44er44    23  18  30  18  29  18  29  -1
s33333  30  30  -1
22222idx 18 -1
```

Comment: A `char` variable cannot hold a name. You need an array to store s C-string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare C-"strings" (which in fact are just `char`-arrays) using the `==`-operator:

```
if(who==stud.id[i]){
```

Use the [`strcmp()` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.4.2) instead:

```
if (strcmp(who, stud.id[i]) == 0) {
```

---

Unrelated, but still important: You want to make sure to not let the user overflow `who`.

You can do this by telling `scanf()` the size of `who` like this:

```
scanf("%14s", who); /* Tell it one less to have a spare char 
                       to store the '0'-terminator. */
```

Although `scanf(()` typically expects an address as argument, you won't pass the address of `who`, but just `who`, because an array (which `who^ is) decays to the address of its 1st element., when being passed to a function.

Comment: Thank you... I'm so tired I completely forgot that... Gonna try it now

Comment: Everything worked. thank you very much :)
Well, in the example i used a file with only a couple of "students" but the exercise actually says that the number of students and the size of their names are undetermined. i just put the size 15 at the beginig to try with a couple only. But thanks for the suggestion, I'll use that too